# How much time vs how many times

Tags: grammar

would some one tell me when we use ” how much time ” and when we use ” how many times ” 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first is using **time** as a measure of elapsed time, or clock time. The second is using **times** to mean occasions, or events.

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as the definition from dictionary, example sentences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["How many...." vs. "How much fish"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119259/how-many-vs-how-much-fish)

Answer (score 3):

The general difference between “how much” and “how many” is that the latter is used for discrete defined amounts, while the former is used for non-discrete undefined quantities. For example:

> How many apples did you eat?
>
> How much food did you eat?

“Apples” can be separated can be separated into individual apples, so there can be 10 apples. There is no discrete entity food can be divided into such that there can be 10 food.

In the case of “time”, the word has a different meaning depending on whether it has an “s” or not. Without an “s” it refers to a period of existence. There is no discrete unit called “time” that you can have, e.g.,10 of. Therefore, you would have to say “how much time”.

The word “times”, however, means occurrences. Since it can be broken down into component parts, e.g., “10 times” which are each a time, you would have to say “how many times”.

Note that even a non-discrete unit such as “time” can easily be converted into a discrete unit such as hours. So you would say “how much time” but “how many hours”.

A useful way to know which phrase to use without having to think too deeply about it is to just follow the singularity/plurality. If a word is plural (like “times”) then it can by definition be broken down into the individual parts, and “how many” is appropriate. If the word is singular (like time) then it probably can’t be broken down any further without changing the word, and therefore “how much” would be appropriate.